# Error in PDO connection: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, easyphp

I am trying to run my project in my local machine but its bringing the following error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\class\user.php on line 21

I have defined the connection:

```
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codecalltut" );
    define( "DB_USERNAME", "root" );
    define( "DB_PASSWORD", "" );
    define( "CLS_PATH", "class" );
```

The line of 21 in user.php is:

```
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
```

What was wrong? Would you help me?

Comment: So what host is defined in `DB_DSN`? What is the full string defined by `DB_DSN`? The error indicates that your network cannot resolve the hostname you specified.

Comment: Have you got the PDO Extension installed correctly ? Also have you tried manually passing through the values into the PDO constructor ?

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? Depending on your database's configuration it will make a world of a difference

Comment: Thanks Bryan Moyles, that's true.. My problem have been solved

Comment: Why don't you even try to help yourself, reading one of hundreds already answered similar questions?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm so sorry..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=codecalltut" );
```

instead of

```
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codecalltut" );
```